# How does mymonero monitor so many Monero private keys and update its balance?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, daemon, mymonero, balance, block-scanning

I'm looking to setup a XMR wallet type service, but was wondering how does mymonero scan so many private keys to update its balance as scanning can take awhile. Is there a method of scanning multiple monero private keys at once using the monero daemon? What is a fast way of scanning multiple private keys? Say I have 1000 XMR private keys to scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wallet uses the daemon to retrieve the bulk transaction data that the wallet then performs computations against to scan for received funds. The wallet checks each transaction with a wallet private view key using elliptic curve operations.

You would want to modify the wallet code to read each transaction once, but then to check multiple private view keys against each transaction. A modern server could easily check many thousands of private view keys per transaction per second.

This would require you to be familiar enough with the Monero codebase to make these changes.

Comment: is there a way to do this without modifying the mondero codebase? would the sweep_all command be able to sweep funds from a private key to my own address? Right now my only solution is to import the private key as a new wallet in Monero and manually update the balance.

Comment: @PatoshiパトシIf you don't modify code, then you'll need to run multiple wallets in parallel. Sweep_all still needs to scan the blockchain before it can transfer any outputs that it detects as incoming, and you can't just hand it a private key for another wallet. Sweep_all will also cause a transaction to occur, which would be very expensive for you.